# ios 9 app not reporting location in background

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am writing (in Swift) an iOS 9 app that needs location updates including in background mode. The problem is that I only get location updates in foreground. I think I have done everything correctly:

In info.plist:

- Specified a value for NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription.
- Specified a value for NSLocationUsageDescription.
- Specified a value for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.
- Included "location" in UIBackgroundModes.
- Included "gps" and "location-services" in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
- Started the location manager as follows:

  ```
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy =
      kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
  locationManager.distanceFilter = 250.0
  locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
  ```
- I have also verified that
  locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically is false.

I get *no* location updates while the app is not in the foreground. The only time I do get location updates is if I bring the app to foreground, and even then, not all the time.

Any idea what's going wrong? Or my expectations incorrect?

Comment: I saw you set distance filter to 250. Did you try a smaller value / Did you walk far enough ?

Comment: A location accuracy of kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters won't use the GPS, so you will probably need to move a fair distance in order to get any updates; possibly in the order of 500-600m.  Where do you allocate your location manager?  Is it a property of your AppDelegate?  If you don't need rapid updates or precise location you may be better off using significant location change monitoring

Comment: I am seeing absolutely no location updates, even after driving 10-30 miles. The updates occur only when I bring the app to the foreground.

Comment: The location manager is a static field of a class, although not AppDelegate. About significant change notification: I saw the same problem there, which is why I switched to standard.

Comment: Could it be some power saving mode that prevents this?

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the app to the background? If you swipe to kill then your app won't automatically restart to receive the location events. I don't see it in your code, did you call requestAlwaysAuthorization? You might also want to implement LocationManager:didFailWithError just to see if that gives you any ideas.